# Using quartz 2.2.0 with tomcat 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat7, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to start a quartz process when tomcat is start up
but it's not working, here is my simple code:
My ServletContextListener:

package quartz.test;

```
 import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
 import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
 import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

 import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
 import org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder;
 import org.quartz.JobBuilder;
 import org.quartz.JobDetail;
 import org.quartz.Scheduler;
 import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
 import org.quartz.Trigger;
 import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
 import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

 public class ApplicationStartup implements ServletContextListener {
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ApplicationStartup.class);
 public static final String QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY = "org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.KEY";
 private StdSchedulerFactory factory = null;

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    try
    {
        factory.getDefaultScheduler().shutdown();
    } catch (SchedulerException ex)
    {
        log.info("catch");
    }
}

public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {

    System.out.println("THE APPLICATION STARTED");
    ServletContext ctx = sce.getServletContext();

    JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob.class).withIdentity("dummyJobName", "group1").build();

    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("dummyTriggerName", "group1")
    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?")).build();

    try {
        factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        ctx.setAttribute(QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY, factory);
        Scheduler scheduler= factory.getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}
My job:

```
package quartz.test;

import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class HelloJob implements Job
{
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {

        System.out.println("Hello Quartz!");
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
     <context-param>
     <param-name>quartz:shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
     <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
     <param-name>quartz:wait-on-shutdown</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
     <param-name>quartz:start-scheduler-on-load</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
     <param-name>quartz:config-file</param-name>
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/quartz.properties</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <listener>
     <listener-class>
        org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener
     </listener-class>
 </listener>
```

EDIT:
**now the job is starting but I am getting error:
20/08/2013 11:18:19 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/monitor] appears to have started a thread named [QuartzTest_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.**

on server when redeploying application into tomcat
Please help

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution,
it's look like a bug in Quartz jobs depends.
in order to make it work add this depends into maven:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

This bug is only on version 2.2.0, on version 2.1.6 it's working OK

Answer (score 0):

To run this example you need at least the two jar-files from Quartz:

```
quartz-2.2.x.jar
quartz-jobs-2.2.x.jar
```